# Relationship between a power set of subsets and a power set of proper subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let ℙ() be the collection of all subsets of , and ℚ() the collection of all *proper* subsets of .

Which of the following hold for every set ?

ℙ() ⊆ ℚ()
ℙ() ⊇ ℚ()
ℙ() ⊃ ℚ()
ℙ() = ℚ()

---

What's exactly wrong with this thought process?

If  = {1,2,3}, then

ℙ() = {∅,{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}}

ℚ() = {∅,{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3}}

`ℙ() ⊆ ℚ()` false. ℙ() is not a subset of ℚ()

`ℙ() ⊇ ℚ()` false. ℙ() is not a superset of ℚ()

`ℙ() ⊃ ℚ()` true. ℙ() is a proper superset of ℚ(), and ℚ() is not equal to ℙ()

`ℙ() = ℚ()` false. ℙ() and ℚ() sets are not subsets of each other.

Comment: P(S) *is* a powerset of Q(S). Proper superset is, in particular, a superset

Comment: How can $\mathbb{P}(S)$ be a proper superset of $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ but not be a superset?

Comment: @Wojowu You mean "superset", not "powerset".

Comment: @MarkKamsma Are you saying that both statements are correct? `ℙ() ⊇ ℚ()` and `ℙ() ⊃ ℚ()`?

Comment: @MarkKamsma Right, thanks

Comment: @GabrielH. That's right.

Comment: @Wojowu Now I get it, thanks! ℙ() is a superset of ℚ() because all elements of ℚ() are elements of ℙ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $A\subseteq B$ is usually defined as $A\subset B$ *or* $A=B$. If one of the two things $A\subset B$ or $A=B$ is true, then $A\subseteq B$ must be true as well. Therefore it is impossible that $\Bbb P(S)\supseteq \Bbb Q(S)$ is false when $\Bbb P(S)\supset \Bbb Q(S)$ is true.

---

Apart from that, your reasoning has another error: you don't need an example set (in your case you use $S=\{1,2,3\}$) to show whether the assertions are true or false. In fact, you *shouldn't* use an example in a proof, since you then just prove a single special case, instead of a general principle. Of course examples are useful to gain intuition, and I highly encourage to first work out a few examples before you start proving something. But for the proof itself, you have to keep things general.

To show the assertions in a general case, we note that for *any* set $S$, the set $S$ itself is a subset of $S$ that is not proper. This follows from the definition of what a *proper subset* is. Furthermore, we know that any proper subset is also a subset (once again by definition of *proper subset*).

- $\Bbb P(S)\not\subseteq \Bbb Q(S)$, since the set $S$ is an element of $\Bbb P(S)$ that is not a subset of $\Bbb Q(S)$.
- $\Bbb P(S)\supseteq\Bbb Q(S)$, since any proper subset is also a subset.
- $\Bbb P(S)\supset\Bbb Q(S)$, since the set $S$ is an element of $\Bbb P(S)$ that is not an element of $\Bbb Q(S)$, therefore $\Bbb P(S)\neq \Bbb Q(S)$.  By the previous point $\Bbb P(S)\supseteq \Bbb Q(S)$, and remember that $\supseteq$ is defined as "$\Bbb P(S)\supset \Bbb Q(S)$ or $\Bbb P(S)= \Bbb Q(S)$". Since the latter is false, the former must be true.
- $\Bbb P(S)\neq \Bbb Q(S)$, as we saw because $S$ is an element in $\Bbb P(S)$ and not in $\Bbb Q(S)$.

Answer (score 0):

According to my point of view, if we take a same example
If  = {1,2,3}, then

ℙ() = {∅,{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}}

ℚ() = {∅,{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3}}

False -> ℙ() ⊆ ℚ() ,  ℙ() is not a subset of ℚ()

True ->  ℙ() ⊇ ℚ() , Because Q(S) is a subset of P(S)e.g Q(S) ⊆ P(S), So that`s why  P(S) is a superset of Q(S) e.g P(S) ⊇ Q(S)

True -> ℙ() ⊃ ℚ()  , ℙ() is a proper superset of ℚ(), and ℚ() is not equal to ℙ()

False -> ℙ() = ℚ() , ℙ() and ℚ() sets are not subsets of each other.